# How can I ensure a grant has been performed?

Tags: oracle

In Oracle, when I run:

```
GRANT SELECT on MYSCHEMA.ORDERS to APP_USER;
```

What query can I run in Oracle to check if this grant exists? I would like to validate that this grant is correctly created in our development, QA, and production databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that from the [`all_tab_privs` performance view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_2110.htm), or the `user_` or `dba_` equivalents depending on your situation and privileges:

```
select *
from all_tab_privs
where table_schema = 'MYSCHEMA'
and table_name = 'ORDERS'
and grantee = 'APP_USER';
```

To see everyone who has access, leave off the `grantee` filter. Note though that the `grantee` may be (and quite probably should be) a role, not an individual user. In that case you'd need to see who has that role granted to get the full picture, and roles can be granted to roles, so that can get a bit recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following (if you are logged in as app_user) :-

```
select owner from user_tab_privs where table_name='Order' and grantee='App_user' and owner='MySchema';
```

If you are logged in as dba, then execute following :-

```
select owner from dba_tab_privs where table_name='Order' and grantee='App_user' and owner='MySchema';
```

If the grant was successful, then the above sql statements should have non-null output.